# What is the best for make charts on iPhone view WebPage?

Tags: javascript, iphone, frameworks, charts

I have to make some charts on a "mobile" website, what is the best framework to do this?

I see Google Charts API, JQuery Visualize, Raphael and JS Charts... but i don't know who is the best one in Safari Mobile.

Thanks in advance to your response.

Answer (score 1):

Google Charts, being rendered as images, are light-weight, require no special libraries or plug-ins and can be viewed on almost anything. They aren't dynamic in the sense that you can't animate them, but for most applications they do a fine job.